# Как объединить код js в один файл

Tags: javascript, php

Я пытаюсь разобраться что натворил разработчик но я не могу понять как это блин работает.

Мне нужно соединить этот файл
https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/master/adminer/static/functions.js

с файлом design.inc.php
https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/2780eb01f5b100a5b4657c4688b9f44d1ef825fe/adminer/include/design.inc.php#L25

Я указал место где он подключается, я бы мог это сделать сам но эта функция script_src

соединяется с этим файлом
https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/5ffec58a8f5424426df93e47e04a24ed95e5aab0/adminer/include/functions.inc.php#L131

файл functions.inc.php я смог объединить поэтому он уже внутри index.php

Помогите понять что с этим делать, я не понимаю как это работает

```
<?php echo script_src("../adminer/static/functions.js"); ?>
<?php echo script_src("static/editing.js"); ?>
```

Comment: файл js - просто функции и переменные. в целевом файле создаешь <script>тут содержимое файла</script>.  функция script_src - банально подключает js файл, то есть создает <script src="путь до файла"></script> что позволяет подключить js к html странице. все просто. самые основы.

Comment: Я так и делал но это почему то не работает